# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have imported an old project to Android Studio
I get this error that I can't solve.
Can you give me a hand?

Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Possible causes:

Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).

```
 lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }



    /*this is needed for after adding 3 library in lib folder for multipart (Start)*/
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
    /*this is needed for after adding 3 library in lib folder for multipart (End)*/

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })

    /*this is needed for using multipart option for sending image to server so we add 3 jar files in lib folder and add dependency from project structure (Start)*/
    compile project(':CircularProgress-google')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
     compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.anshulagarwal06:PasswordEditText:v1.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.taishi-y:flipprogressdialog:0.1.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.jksiezni.permissive:permissive:0.2'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:6.2'
    compile 'com.github.bhargavms:DotLoader:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.minube:Text-Length-Bar:beta-1.0'
    compile 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Comment: `compile` is deprecated, try with `implementation` instead